# Entity framework code first delete entities without parent

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, cascade

I have two entities Users and Phone. Relationship is one to one. Mapping is

```
public class User 
{
    public virtual Phone Phone { get; set;}

    public virtual int PhoneId { get; set;}
}

public class Phone 
{
    public virtual string Number { get; set;}
}
```

My mapping for User is:

```
HasRequired(x => x.Phone).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.PhoneId)
```

I have user with assigned phone.
f.e.

```
Phone oldPhone = new Phone();
Phone newPhone = new Phone();
User user = new User();
user.Phone = old;

///Save user with phone.

user.Phone = newPhone;
///Save user  with phone.
```

Now I have user with assigned phone - newPhone and not assigned oldPhone row in the DB.

How can I setup mapping to delete entity without parent(oldPhone).

EDITED.

I have changed mapping according [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/19/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-one-to-one-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) article to

```
 HasRequired(x => x.Phone).WithOptional();
```

For save I use this method:

```
public override void Save(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }

            if (entity.Id > 0)
            {
                DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
                DbContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);   
            }            
        }
```

When I attached new entity old ones doesn`t deleted from DB, so in my example I have two entities in DB oldPhone and newPhone.

Comment: First, your premises should be right. `WithMany()` is not 1:1. Second, what exactly happens in your example that you did not expect? And what code should be behind `Save user with phone`?

Comment: Fixed first and second and third

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to do this through mapping in EF. For one of my projects I have made a Parent attribute, which I could check on Save. I think you could use it here to. I have made a blog post on this with code; [extending entity framework 4 with parentvalidator](http://wimpool.nl/blog/DotNet/extending-entity-framework-4-with-parentvalidator). 
It would require to add the User property to the Phone entity.

```
[Parent]
public virtual User User { get; set;}
```